# SSLStrip with autologin

Tags: tls, linux, sslstrip

What can I do to sniff the traffic by SSLStrip when the user has automatic login to the site?

Comment: why do you think that you would have a problem with auto-login?

Comment: @schroeder think about it. 
anyway sslstrip is useless on sites like facebook twitter etc because hsts .

Comment: your comment makes no sense

Comment: @schroeder why?

Answer (score 1):

Because HTTP is a stateless protocol each request from the client contains information which let the server resume the established logged in session. This information is usually in the form of a session cookie and if you get access to the unencrypted request you can extract the session cookie and use it to take over the established session.

For more details see the [Wikipedia article about session hijacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking).